# How to set a delegate when ViewController already has a delegate?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uialertview

I have an iPhone app which sends an email.  If the "To:" address is not set, I display an Alert (UIAlertView).  At the present time, I do not check for the user tapping OK, I just go on my merry way! :D

I am getting the following error when tapping OK on the Alert:

> wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003

I believe it's because I don't handle the tapping of OK and it's still showing when the app is doing something else.  So, after doing some research on SO and Google, it appears I have to have this:

```
- (void) Alert: (NSString *) title andData: (NSString *) errorMsg  {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: title
                          message: errorMsg 
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];


    return;

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"button was pressed");
}
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to set up the delegate for this.  I already have a delegate:

```
@interface ReportViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>  {
```

How do I set the delegate so the tap of the OK button is handled, thus removing the error?

Comment: I would recommend really understanding the delegate design pattern and not just fixing this problem. It's one of the most useful things for you to understand. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the angle brackets, you can provide a comma-separated list of protocols.

```
@interface ReportViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>  {
```

Now you can implement both sets of methods. And don't forget to set the alert view's delegate to `self`.

Comment: I have edited my question to show the pertinent code.  Delegates are one of my weakest areas of expertise; therefore, I'm not sure what you are referring to.  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I gave you the change for the @interface line. And when you create the alert view, pass in `self` for the parameter to `delegate:` instead of `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Your delegate looks like nil as per your code `'delegate:nil'` in the question. You need to change it to `'delegate:self'`.